# Quartz: Show trigger interval/schedule details

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

How can I get the interval/schedule details of an existing trigger?

In our application a user can reschedule a job by setting an interval in minutes. We need to compare the value they submit with the schedule of the current trigger to determine whether a reschedule is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`Scheduler.getTrigger()`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#getTrigger%28org.quartz.TriggerKey%29) method which returns an instance of [`Trigger`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html). You can downcast it and read all required information like the schedule (CRON/simple) and associated job.

Comment: I already had the trigger instance but needed to cast it as an `ISimpleTrigger` (not sure if this differs from Java version) which gave me access to `ISimpleTrigger.RepeatInterval`.

Comment: @BenFoster: I missed the fact that you are using Quartz.NET but I'm glad it still worked :-).